# React - copying state not returning new object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to copy my state in a components function in React so I can alter the object in order to make an Ajax request.

Here is my code:

```
fetchNewThumbnails = () => {

    const { publicationsFilter, currentQuery } = this.state;

    const params = Object.assign({}, currentQuery);

    console.log(params)
    console.log(currentQuery)

    if (publicationsFilter !== 'All') {
      params.test = 'test';
    }

    // some Ajax request here

}
```

The issue is when I edit the copied `params` object in my if statement. When I copy this and run the function a second time with my `publicationsFilter` set to `'All'` I would expect the copied `params` object to just be a copy of the state without the `test` key in the object but it's still there from the previous time the function ran.

Logging the `currentQuery` object always returns the state without the `params.test` key in there so I would have thought it would just copy the `currentQuery` object as it is rather than keeping the previous `params` object.

Not entirely sure where i've gone wrong, please let me know if anything is unclear!

**EDIT**

currentQuery object looks like this:

```
filter: {
    content_type: "thumbnail",
    fields.thumbnailType.fields.type[match]: "News & Press",
    fields.thumbnailType.sys.contentType.sys.id: "thumbnailType"
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to have your ajax code below, do you alter state after receiving the answer?

Comment: I do alter the state but with none of the values that are listed above. Also this is shown as the currentQuery object remains untouched, its just the params object that assumes its previous altered state ( of having a test key added to it) when I run the function again

Comment: This is weird... I would like to say maybe the `param` variable when instantiated it retrieves its old value? But that's not how const work, they're supposed to be block-scoped...

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're not assigning `.test = "test"` to the state later on in your code?

Comment: I promise i'm not Fabio

Comment: It's not possible for the params object to be the "same" object, meaning it's not the same location in memory. You're creating a new object each time. If might have the same shape, meaning the `test` key is added again.

Comment: @RossAllen I mean, that's the point - how the hell does the `test` property end up in there, if `currentQuery` does not have a `test` property

Comment: What does `currentQuery` look like?

Comment: Posted above in edit

Comment: @redhouse87 Do you have a lot of enemies? My best guess is someone is trying to pull a joke on you, and they overwrote `Object.assign` implementation - that's how clueless I am lol. I will stop trying now, sorry. Can't figure it out.

Comment: You aren't logging `publicationsFilter`. Are you sure it's `'All'`?

Comment: Yes I had a log in there before, i'm 100% sure

Comment: Type `debugger` in your code and open the inspector so you can step through it line-by-line. I think you'll find the answer pretty quickly. It's tough to tell with only small bits of code because everything seems okay from what you've posted.